# How i read multiple array from json with javascript and put the value in a grid?

Tags: javascript, json, devextreme

how i read all the "Value" from this json with javascript ?
This json have multiple array inside and i need to put the value in a grid like dxDataGrid devextreme component.

```
{
    "result": [
    {
    "DATA": [
    {
    "NAME": "Value1",
    "DESCRIPTION": "Value2",
    "DATA": [
    {
    "NAME2": "Value3",
    "DATA2": [
    {
    "NAME3": "Value4"
    }
    ]
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "NAME": "Value5",
    "DESCRIPTION": "Value6",
    "DATA": [
    {
    "NAME2": "Value7",
    "DATA2": [
    {
    "NAME4": "Value8"
    }
    ]
    }
    ]
    },
    ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: DevExtreme have sample code on their site.  See https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/AjaxRequest/jQuery/Light/, for example

Answer (score 0):

You can try using for in loop for traversing through a json object like this:

```js
    var data = JSON.parse('
{
  "result": [
    {
      "DATA": [
        {
          "NAME": "Value1",
          "DESCRIPTION": "Value2",
          "DATA": [
            {
              "NAME2": "Value3",
              "DATA2": [
                {
                  "NAME3": "Value4"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "NAME": "Value5",
          "DESCRIPTION": "Value6",
          "DATA": [
            {
              "NAME2": "Value7",
              "DATA2": [
                {
                  "NAME4": "Value8"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        
      ]
    }
  ]
}')

for (var event in data) {
    var dataCopy = data[event];
    for (data in dataCopy) {
        var mainData = dataCopy[data];
        for (key in mainData) {
            if (key.match(/name|value/)) {
                alert('key : ' + key + ':: value : ' + mainData[key])
            }
        }
    }
}​
```